# Resetear el new Blob() y el new FormData() en vanilla Js

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una aplicación en donde paso un json a otro json, mi duda es que cuando paso los datos hacia el PHP, quiero limpiar el new Blob() para tenerlo disponible para la siguiente carga de datos.
A continuación mi código:

```js
const data = new FormData();
            const jsonBlob = new Blob([jsonaux], {type: "application/json"});

            data.append("datajson", jsonBlob);

            data.append("Flagcreartxt",Flagfiletxt);
            data.append("TxtName",txtname);

            //console.log(data.has('datajson'));
            
            fetch("model/importBud.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: data
            })   
            .then(resp => {
                if(!resp.ok) {
                    const err = new Error("Response wasn't okay");
                    err.resp = resp;
                    throw err;
                }
                console.log(resp);
                alert('Ready...');
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                return;
    
            });
```

Lo único que quiero hacer es resetear esta línea para vaciar el Blob()

```js
const jsonBlob = new Blob([jsonaux], {type: "application/json"});
```

Y resetear esta línea para vaciar el FormData()

```js
const data = new FormData();
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a saber como hacerlo o tendrán alguna sugerencia?
Por anticipado gracias.

Comment: Creo que si en lugar de `const` usas `let` y al terminar de usarlos haces un  `jsonBlob = undefined; delete jsonBlob; data = undefined; delete data;` ya queda limpio